# JavaScript calling XML Array - Undefined Error

Tags: javascript, xml, arrays, undefined

I'm really new to XML and fairly new to Javascript, and I'm having some problems. I wrote some JavaScript code a while ago with an array of images that were frames of a gif, so that you could individually control the frames if you wanted to. I wanted to use an XML file for the images instead of having huge arrays in my JS file (each gif was 38 frames and there were 6 gifs...), but now when I try to call the images in the array I get /devDirectory/undefined instead of devDirectory/images/example.jpg coming up in the console.

Here is the XML code I'm using:

CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
  <directories>
    <imagePath>images/</imagePath>
  </directories>
  <myimages>
    <eyeimage>eyeframes1.jpg</eyeimage>
    <eyeimage>eyeframes2.jpg</eyeimage>
    <eyeimage>eyeframes3.jpg</eyeimage>
-----ETC. (this continues until eyeframes38)-----   
    <stomachimage>stomachframes1.jpg</stomachimage>
    <stomachimage>stomachframes2.jpg</stomachimage>
    <stomachimage>stomachframes3.jpg</stomachimage>
-----ETC. (this continues until stomachframes38)-----
  </myimages>
</data>
```

And here's the JavaScript:

CODE:

```
 var eyeFrames = new Array;

$(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "xml/sample.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: parseXml
            });
        });
        function parseXml(xml){
            var thumbHtml;
            var imageDir = $(xml).find("directories").find("imagePath").text();
            $(xml).find("eyeimage").each(function(){
                var eyeImage = $(this).find("eyeimage").text();
                thumbHtml = imageDir + eyeImage;            
                eyeFrames.push(thumbHtml);
            });
            playFrames();   
        };
    function playFrames() {
            var i=0;
    setInterval(function() { 
    if(i<38) {
            i++;
            document.getElementById('eye').src = eyeFrames[i].src;
        }
        else {
        i=0;
    }

    }, 720);

}
function checkFrame() {
        if(i=38){
            i=0;
}
}
```

If anyone could help me figure out why I'm getting undefined instead of the actual images, that would be great!
Thank you for your time :)